# How to turn off grid auto adjust to other divs?

Tags: css, css-grid

After I add anything into the one of the 3 divs others height expands to fit the biggest one is there any way to remove this auto sizing? Code example (box1 and box3 expand to the size of box2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gridBody">
        <div> box1 (show this without the width of the second line)</div>
        <div> box2<div> second line</div> </div>
        <div> box3 (show this without the width of the second line)</div>
    </div>

    <style>
        .gridBody {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
        }
        .gridBody div {
            margin: 20px;
            padding: 20px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);

        }
    </style>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried `grid-auto-rows/grid-auto-columns:min-content` and expected it to adjust the size of box1 and box3 to the minimal content but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you could add `align-items: start` to `gridBody` to avoid other `div` expanding height to fit the biggest one.

By default, grid layout will place the items in a behavior similar to `align-items: stretch`, which resulted in all `div` stretched to the full height.

[More about `align-items`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items)

Example:

```css
.gridBody {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  /*  Add this line */
  align-items: start;
}

.gridBody div {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="gridBody">
  <div> box1 (show this without the width of the second line)</div>
  <div> box2
    <div> second line</div>
  </div>
  <div> box3 (show this without the width of the second line)</div>
</div>
```